# Warning: ColVis requires DataTables 1.7 or greater - www.datatables.net/download

Tags: datatables, prestashop-1.6

I am new in prestashop and i am using data tables latest library 1.9 in prestashop for products showing in my module but i have got one warning message regarding Colvis option.The page pop ups a warning message "Warning:ColVis requires 1.7 or greater-www.datatables.net/download".I have checked the colvis library and the version code is colVis 1.0.7 and its the recent version.I dont know why this happened.Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the version of dataTables itself that should be at least 1.7.x.